# Laravel query - request for a phrase to the translation table

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with finding results. I search the 'name' records in the translation table for the occurrence of any of the words.

```
//Bad result:
return Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($findTextWildcards) {
                    foreach ($findTextWildcards as $value) {
                        $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                    }
                });

//good result but difficult query
        return Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->where(function ($query) use ($findTextWildcards) {
                    foreach ($findTextWildcards as $value) {
                        $query->whereHas('translations', function ($q) use ($value){
                            $q->where('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. Probably the problem was that you didn't wrap this with additional `where` closure.

```
return Product::whereIn('id', $ids)
     ->whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($findTextWildcards) {
              $query->where(function($query) use ($findTextWildCards) {
                    foreach ($findTextWildcards as $value) {
                        $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                    }
               });
        });
```